# How to pass value from my class file to xaml file?

Tags: xamarin

I'm learning Xamarin, and I'm trying to understand how can I pass a value from my class file to a .xmal file for display?  Is that data binding or something else.

Example:
My file.cs

```
namespace MyApp.Views
{
    public partial class LandingPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LandingPage()
        {
           string myvalue = "hello world";
        }
     }
}
```

file.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label Text="myvalue" />
</StackLayout>
```

I want the "myvalue" to pass from my class to my xaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/) is the answer

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyValue}" />
```

you can only bind to **public properties**

```
public string MyValue { get; set; }

public LandingPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   MyValue = "hello world";

   this.BindingContext = this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason, could you explain why you put this line `this.BindingContext = this;`

Comment: BindingContext tells the page what data source is used for the bindings.  Typically this would be your ViewModel, but in this case you are using the page itself as the source.  Please read the binding docs for a complete explanation.